# Scala abstract value members on list returning unexpected result?

Tags: scala, arity

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I don't understand Scala well enough. I was playing in the REPL today with some list functions. Here's what I did:

First, I created a list:

```
scala> val myList = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
myList: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Next, I created another list by prepending another double:

```
scala> val newMyList = 4.0 :: myList
newMyList: List[Double] = List(4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Now, when I ask for the productArity (List.productArity) on newMyList:

```
scala> print(newMyList.productArity)
2
```

It appears to still be treating the first list differently from the other list. Is this an intended behavior or is it a bug?

```
scala> print(newMyList.productElement(0))
4.0
scala> print(newMyList.productElement(1))
List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

*Note, I get a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to access elements higher than 0, 1. 2 should return 2.0, and 3 should return 3.0, right?*

Answer (score 5):

A `List` in Scala is a cons-cell based construction similar to the lists used in the LISP language: It consists of cells each of which has a head element and a tail element, where the last cell has a tail element of `Nil`.

An empty cell in Scala is `Nil`, a non-empty cell is `::` (aka "Cons"). These two concrete sub-types of list are implemented as case classes that provide the `Product` trait to which you refer.

So instead of

```
List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

You can think of

```
::(1.0, ::(2.0, ::(3.0, Nil)))
```

or graphically explained

```
Cons(1.0, .)
          Cons(2.0, .)
                    Cons(3.0, .)
                              Nil
```

A `::` is a product of arity 2, the first element is the head, the second the tail. That's why you get `4` and `List(1, 2, 3)` as the two product elements to your second list.

To access an element of the list, you would use `apply` instead. The list size is given by `size`:

```
List(4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0).apply(2) // -> 2.0
List(4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0).size     // -> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible cases for a `List` - `Nil` and `::`.

`::` is defined something like:

```
case class ::[A](val head: A, val tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

so it is a product with two elements, the head of the list and the tail.

This is why `productArity` of a non-empty list returns 2 since you are calling `::.productArity`.

In contrast, `Nil.productArity` returns 0.

`newMyList.productElement(0)` is the head of the list since you are getting the first element from a `::`, and `newMyList.productElement(1)` is the tail of the list. There are no more elements of a `Cons` instance, so any index greater than 1 is out of bounds.

If you want to index the list itself you can use the `apply` method:

```
print(newMyList(2))
```